# Разработка адаптивного сайта, тестирование медиазапросов

Tags: адаптивная-верстка

Верстаю шапку сайта, столкнулся с проблемой, chrome инструменты для разработчика показывают версию сайта на iphone без учета границ браузера..
Соответственно на телефоне потом выглядит иначе, т.к. сафари добавляет навигацию, и область просмотра оказывается меньше, чем отображает chrome инструменты на пк.

Есть ли возможность нормально тестировать сайт при разработке, сразу учитывая границы браузера chrome?